# What does "tomber dans les pommes" mean?

Tags: proverbes

I'm wondering what "tomber dans les pommes" means. I don't know what it is. I once knew what it meant, but not anymore now. I don't understand the French meaning of It.

Comment: Please make sure to look in the dictionary first for such expressions : [_Larousse_](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pomme/62473/locution?q=tomber+dans+les+pommes#317940), [_Collins_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/tomber-dans-les-pommes). See [this](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thank you!

Comment: I know that, but what is the English Translation for this? I don't understand the meaning of it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I pressed Larousse

Comment: And [wiktionnary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tomber_dans_les_pommes). A question on the origin of the phrase would have been more appropriate for FL, and the answer to this is [here](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/tomber-dans-les-pommes.php), same answer in *Le Dictionnnaire Culturel en Langue Française*.

Comment: It is just a specific expression. Meaning has already been done, and can be found in dictionaries.

Comment: La [lettre](https://books.google.com/books?id=VNwLAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA99&dq=%22pommes+cuites%22+sand&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD66zB45_KAhXLGh4KHQYZBnIQ6AEIZjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22pommes%20cuites%22&f=false) de Madame Dupin en question, à sa mère.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tomber dans les pommes" is an expression meaning "s'évanouir" which can be translated in "To pass out" in English.

Comment: Please read the [following](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). For instance off topic questions shouldn't be answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It means "to pass out" or "to faint".